# How to remove grease stains from clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I was eating pizza and I got some grease on one of my nicer shirts (I know, I probably shouldn't eat pizza and wear nice clothes). The stain is pretty visible and after washing the shirt, it was still there. Getting rid of the shirt is not an option. **How can I get a grease stain off of clothes?** It's made out of cotton if that would change anything, but I would prefer a method that would work on other kids of fabric too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My normal course of action to take out a stain is to put dish soap on the stain, then hold the garment with two hands on either side of the stain about an inch or so apart and work the fabric back and forth. Also go in a circular motion against both hands. The stain will become fainter and fainter until gone or unnoticeable.

If greasy, work cooking oil into the stain using the method described above, first. The oil will dissolve and loosen grease within the fabric, and the oil can be easily washed out.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me, I just use neat detergent (I use liquid detergent in my washing machine) - I stick my finger in some of the washing solution/detergent and apply it to the grease stain direct, rubbing it in a bit, and repeating as often as necessary to cover the stain. Put it through the wash immediately, and the stain disappears. I'd guess this method is more successful with some brands of liquid detergent than others though, so if all else fails, Fairy liquid (dishwashing detergent), applied in the same way, then washed in the usual way in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. You are out of luck removing a grease stain that changes the appearance of a fabric if the piece has been dried by heat (such as a clothes dryer) which will "set" the discolouration.

You have created a "pinto" version of your nice shirt.